# How to select multiple rows from UIPickerView ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8

I want to select more then one rows from UIPickerView and place in UITextField . Language used in my project is objective c . I can't understand logic

Comment: it is better to make your own using `UITableView`

Comment: i can't understand logic how to do that

Comment: You need to implement multiple selection in `UITableView`. @MuhammadAdeelQureshi

Comment: @iPeter can i replace UIPickerView with UITableView???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much I have understood what you want to achieve is you want to select more than one item from a list and show it in a `UITextField`. For that you can do this:

At first Drag and drop a `UITableView` into your `storyboard` and connect `datasource` and `delegates`.

Drag an `UITableViewCell` into your `tableview` and give the `reuserIdentifier` as **TableCell**.

Drag an `UILabel` and an `UIImageView` onto your `tableCell`. Give tags to your `label` and `imageView` as **888** and **999**. Make the `imageview` like a small box and place it just beside your `label`.

Take an `array` for showing the list you want to show user to select items and populate the `UITableView` with it.

Take another `array` in which you want to store the selected items.

Just under your implementation declare two arrays like this:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    NSMutableArray *arrItems;
    NSMutableArray *arrSelectedItems; 

}
```

Now in your `viewDidLoad` populate your item `array`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arrItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item%d",i+1] forKey:@"itemName"];
        [dict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"isSelected"]; 
        [arrItems addObject:dict]
    }
    arrSelectedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

Now implement the `DataSource` and `Delegate` methods of `UITableView`.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return arrItems.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell"];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [arrItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *lblItemName = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:888];
    lblItemName.text = [dict valueForKey:@"itemName"];

    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:999];
    if ([[dict valueForKey:@"isSelected"]isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
         imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
         imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Now implement the multiple selection login in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like below:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([arrSelectedItems containsObject:dict]) {
        [arrSelectedItems removeObject:dict];
    } else {
        [arrSelectedItems addObject:dict];
    }
    if ([[dict valueForKey:@"isSelected"]isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        [dict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"isSelected"];
    } else {
        [dict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"isSelected"];
    }
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    //Here you can show the selected Objects in `UITextField`
    self.yourTexField.text = [arrSelectedItems componentsJoinedByString:@","];
}
```

> P.S: I have written the total code here, haven't tested it, so if any errors occurs feel free to leave a comment below, I will be there to solve it.

I think it will help you.

Comment: Happy to help. :) Happy Coding. :) Please upvote the answer if you can. :P

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new tableview with each row as a language, then present it when user respond to textfield. 
You can look [here](https://ktrkathir.wordpress.com/2015/04/21/how-to-design-a-uitableview-with-multiple-selection-in-ios/) for some starter code on how to implement the multiple selection logic.
A textfield has a property call `inputview`, you can try replacing that with tableview.